# Torrents not downloading on a QNAP TS209 NAS

Tags: linux, nas, bittorrent

I have a Linux-based NAS from QNAP, which comes with a built-in torrent downloader.  I have never really had reason to moan until about three weeks ago, when it suddenly stopped downloading anything.

I thought I'd try TorrentFlux and have installed and configured it to run on the QNAP's in-built Web server.  I loaded the same torrents and it too has sat 'Waiting' for the last few days without downloading anything.

So, I went back to using Azareus/Vuze on my Windows PC (behind the same firewall) and it has started downloading 80% of the torrents straight away and estimates finishing in about four hours (the rest do not show any seeds, so fair enough).

Given that Vuze is working without issue and neither app sees to work on the NAS, I can only assume that there is something iffy with the NAS setuup.  I'm not much of a Linux guy, so don't really know where to start looking.

I realise that this a bit vague, as I can't narrow it down to specifics, but has anyone got ideas how I might diagnose this?  I would really rather use the QNAP, so I don't have to keep my PC running all day.

Comment: I'm torn - QNAP == Server Fault but Torrents == Superuser (at best)...

Comment: superuser on the basis that it's a consumer-level device.

Comment: might be a silly question at this point, but I feel I should ask: does QGET (qnaps own torrent software) work?